# Which transistor and resistor(s) do I need to hook up the FSA-410BT smoke alarm to Raspberry Pi's gpio?

Tags: transistors, component-selection

The documentation for the smoke alarm: http://cms.dsc.com/download.php?t=1&id=16756

When the alarm is going off, this device draws 25mA (max) and idles at 20µA. It's 12v too, and I'm sure that complicates it.

I would like for the non-alarm state to be closed, and the alarm state to be open.

I know there are many transistor types, but I'm completely ignorant of the differences in any meaningful ways (some allow higher currents or lower currents, some higher voltages or lower... not very useful).

Is this even possible in a single device, considering that the alarm is 12v while the gpio is 3.3v?

I intend for the cable to be between 12ft and 25ft. I have not selected a particular kind, and if this affects the answer I can choose whatever is recommended (shielded, gauge, solid/stranded). If this is sensitive to the exact length of the cable, I can get the measuring tape out and provide something more specific (to within +/- 8 inches or so) in a few hours.

This model does not include the optional (LED) terminals.

Comment: have you asked this before? .... i have seen this exact question before .... if you have not, then is this a school work assignment?

Comment: you are on the wrong track .... have a close look at the wiring diagram on page 2 .... the alarm circuit has no voltages .... it is only a switch ..... so the question is, how do you monitor a switch with an RPi?

Comment: not quite @jsotola. if he does not have the optional SPDT relay , the question is **how to get a NC to C signal from NO and C** and not affect 20uA much during idle nor the 25mA max. . Question how long is the cable and is it shielded? (STP) and BTW all transistors invert with proper bias as a logic inverter.

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt I have updated the question regarding cabling. I'm flexible on what will be used. Is this a simpler issue if I get the relay?

Comment: Do you have a current limit in mind for On/Off state with an inverter and a preference for low current/ more part complexity for CMOS protection for ESD and external bias present?

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt I definitely don't want to risk ruining hardware, and if I can be more careful rather than less careful I'd prefer that. It's also important that this performs robustly... I don't want to bailing-wire-and-duct-tape it.

Comment: Do you have the optional interface? If not that negates Jacks answer and the 20uA idle current.  ie. does it rely on battery only or have external DC

Comment: The solution may be trivial but the problem is to clearly define the interfaces and environmental noise. But <1uA 10k gate pullup  to 12V  from Gate of a Nch FET can create a Logic "0" signal across Drain (signal) to Source=Gnd with ESD output protection added and ouput to a 10k Pullup on drain output to 3.3V at uC end with grounds common so , when Alarm goes off, Nch switches off. and uC sees a logic 1.  THis is pretty common or you can use a noninverting switch solution. These are all over the web and here. aka "level shifters"

Answer (score 3):

From the datasheet/instructions you can see that the alarm provides for a remote LED and a floating NO/NC switch. The LED may be your best option.
You should use this to activate an optocoupler that will drive the Raspberry Pi I/O pin.

I'd recommend you use something like the [H11L1](http://www.everlight.com/file/ProductFile/H11L1.pdf) which can work with your 3.3 V levels on the 'Pi.

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGh6pz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You also have a NO/NC floating contact you could use and the Alarm NO contacts (though this I'd recommend you don't use if you have other connections here).

[image]

Comment: The open-collector output needs a pullup.

Comment: Led draws half as much as the alarm when off and then the NO contact can shunt the LED. He wants NC output to verify connectivity

Comment: @CL I would assume that you do not need a pullup resistor. Given the way they've formed the connections I would assume the LED+ is a supply line and LED- is an OC driver. It would make no sense to have to provide another 12V or 24 V line to provide a pullup. I'd also assume that there is some resistance already in the LED+ line so the pins are short circuit proof.

Comment: I meant the output of the H11L1.

Comment: @CL For a slow speed application such as this, the internal pullup on the MCU is normally sufficient, so an external pullup would not be required.